# Python. Как взять из списка (list) число, если там строка и число находится в ней?

Tags: python, строки, list, числа

Не могли бы подсказать, как в Python сложить все числа из подобного списка, если числа находятся вместе со словами и по сути являются строкой?

```
list_product = ['moduct 500', 'doduct 1200', 'funduk 200', 'kuduk 500']
```

Буду очень благодарен =)

Comment: разделите строку с помощью split и преобразуйте вторую часть в число

Comment: Либо с помощью регулярных выражений найти числа в строках

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
list_product = ['moduct 500', 'doduct 1200', 'funduk 200', 'kuduk 500']
sum=0
for el in list_product:
    sum+=int(el.split()[1])
print('Сумма',sum)
```

Вывод:

```
Сумма 2400
```

Comment: Вау, очень лаконично выглядит! 
Если вам не трудно, можете подсказать узнать откуда берётся el в 'el in list_product'? Остальную часть кода я вроде бы как понимаю..

Comment: *el* Это имя переменной, можете назвать как вам удобно, например *n* или *item_list*,

Comment: Не сочтите за дерзость, последнее уточнение у вас узнать. Я немного тут не понимаю работу цикла for, почему он запускается, когда после in мы передаём ему значение список...

Comment: Боюсь, что не смогу объяснить вам доходчиво и максимально полно, как работает функция for in, в рамках этого комментария, конкретно в этом случае, обрабатывается каждый элемент списка list_product . Более подробно рассмотреть этот вопрос позволит статья которую я нашел в поиске: https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/tsikly-upravlenie-vetvleniem-python/tsikl-for-in/

Comment: Большое вам, человеческое спасибо